# Web Page with folder navigation

Tags: c#, navigation, local

I'm needing to create a (currently) locally hosted web page that basically functions like a folder browser to choose which slideshow to present.  for example:  I have a base folder on a drive called `MainSlideshowFolder` and in this directory there are multiple folders that contain a either more folders or a bunch of images.

```
MainSlideshowFolder
        Garden
             Flowers
                   Image1
                   Image2
                    ...
             Trees
                   Image1
                   Image2
                    ...
        Stars
             Image1
             Image2
              ...
```

I'm wanting the user to see the click-able text `Garden` and below that `Stars`.  if they click `Stars` then it just shows the slideshow, but if they select `Garden` it shows the two subfolders `Flowers` and `Trees`.

I'm fairly confident I can create the slideshow, however I am uncertain as to how I would create the `Folder Navigation` portion.  What is typically the best method to perform this type of navigation?

Comment: What you're probably looking for is a "tree view" control. There are a lot of javascript/jQuery plugins that can accomplish exactly this, but you'd need to provide your own logic on how to populate these. A quick google search for Javascript or jQuery Tree View should give you a wealth of options.

Comment: @trnelson  thank you for the information!  I will go google those right now!